# Groups in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm reading an online book on Python which explains regular expressions, but I can't understand what groups in regular expressions are.

For example what is the difference between :

```
regex = re.compile(r'Name (\w)*')
regex.findall('Name Mahmoud')
```

and:

```
regex = re.compile(r'Name \w*')
regex.findall('Name Mahmoud')
```

Why does the first call of `findall()` method gives me `['d']` but the second call of it gives me `['Name Mahmoud']`?

Comment: That is because your regex capturing group is expecting a single `\w`. Try this: `re.compile(r'Name (\w*)')`

Comment: Why does the second one gives me `['Name Mahmoud']`?

Comment: You should play with e.g. http://regex101.com/#python - and use `regex.search` rather that `regex.findall`, then you can see the `.groups()` in more detail.

Comment: The second one should give you the result that Kevin said. As it has no groups and the pattern match the whole text.

Comment: I'm sorry.I've edited it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex groups are used to capture part of a regex.

- `Name (\w)*` capture a single character `\w`, and that capture is repeated many times `*`. You will only find the latest capture in your result (`d` of `Mahmoud`)
- `Name \w*` does not use group ...
- `Name (\w*)` capture a series of characters `\w*` which in your case will yield `Mahmoud`.

For further information refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Thank you ! I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

### What is a group in a regular expression?

A group is one matching pair of parentheses typically with stuff between them. Groups serve three primary purposes:

1. A group may have multiple alternatives separated by the `"|"` logical OR metacharacter.
2. A group allows applying a quantifier to repeat the contents of the group a specified number of times.
3. A *capture group* is a special type of group where the contents of the group are saved and available both inside the regex (using `"\n"` backreference syntax), and outside the regex (using `"$n"` syntax). Capture groups are numbered starting with 1 and are counted in order of the occurence of the opening parentheses.

Comment: But what this expression means "regex = re.compile(r'Name (\w)\w*')"?