# Groups in regular expressions (follow up)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.5

I just asked a question about groups in regular expressions ([Groups in regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438620/groups-in-regular-expressions/33439814#33439814))
.And I got the answer.Now I have another one related with the previous :
What do these hole expressions mean :

```
regex = re.compile('Name (\w)\w*')  # what I mean by adding \w* after (\w)

regex = re.compile('Name (\w)\w')   # what I mean by adding \w after (\w)
```

Thanks again !

Comment: Please read http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html  or http://www.digitalamit.com/article/regular_expression/2.phtml. ``\w`` means "Match a word character (includes alphabets, numbers and underscore)", ``*`` means "zero or more".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a custom regex pattern - explanation as below

### Name (\w)\w*

```
Name (\w)\w*
```

Options: Case insensitive

- Match the character string “Name ” literally (case insensitive) `Name`
- Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 `(\w)`

  - Match a single character that is a “word character” (letter, digit, or underscore in the active code page) `\w`
- Match a single character that is a “word character” (letter, digit, or underscore in the active code page) `\w*`

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`

Comment: Thank you ! :) I got it.